# How to know if google account is deleted/suspended in frontend website

Tags: reactjs, oauth, google-oauth

I have integrated Google oAuth in React Website.

- Once the user is signed in using Google oAuth backend generates jwt token for the user and stores in localstorage for further communications with api server

Now I delete the gmail account so how does the frontend or backend knows the status of the account since the user is already logged in on frontend with valid jwt.